# C programming with getopt(): giving command line flags criteria

Tags: c, debugging, command-line-arguments, getopt, getopt-long

I am beginning to teach myself C. I have run into a few bumps here and there but right now I am stumped by `getOpt()`. The main thing thats giving me trouble is when I try to make certain flags dependent on other flags. For example I want these to work:

```
./myfile -a -b -c blue
```

But none of the other options to work without -a. Thus `./myfile -b -c purple` would be invalid. Is it possible for getopt to handle this kind of "flag dependent" criteria? How would I go about doing that? Secondly, lets say that no matter which flags are passed, along with it must be a colour.

So `./myfile -a -b green` and `./myfile red` are both valid. I understand that this all lies within the options parameter of getOpt() (which is currently set up to look something like this "abc"), but how would I make one parameter required for each instance without doing "a:b:c:" since this would not include the mandatory colour if no flags are passed.

Comment: The first question (make -b only valid in combination with -a) is not possible with getopt - however it's easy to check that situation on your own when iterating over the given parameters.

Comment: How would I iterate over the parameters? Im sorry, again very new to C. How can I iterate over parameters

Comment: You always iterate over the parameters when you're using getopt. You are simply calling `getopt` multiple times. (Note that this function internally stores it's state, so it always knows which parameter to return next). abligh already posted an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the example (from the manpage) of `getopt`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int flags, opt;
  int nsecs, tfnd;

  nsecs = 0;
  tfnd = 0;
  flags = 0;
  while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "nt:")) != -1)
    {
      switch (opt)
        {
        case 'n':
          flags = 1;
          break;
        case 't':
          nsecs = atoi (optarg);
          tfnd = 1;
          break;
        default:               /* '?' */
          fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s [-t nsecs] [-n] name\n", argv[0]);
          exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

  printf ("flags=%d; tfnd=%d; optind=%d\n", flags, tfnd, optind);

  if (optind >= argc)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Expected argument after options\n");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  printf ("name argument = %s\n", argv[optind]);

  /* Other code omitted */

  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Note you'll need to add some declarations, and a `main()` function to get that to work.

You can see the example `n` above is a flag, and works like your `b` option. The `t` option above takes a parameter and works like your `c` option. If you want to have an `a` option that is also a flag, you would make the `getopt` parameter `"abf:"` (i.e. add an `a` in without a colon), and a stanza to the `switch` like this:

```
         case 'a':
                 aflag = 1;
                 break;
```

having first set `aflag` to 0. At the end you would check for the illegal condition where other options were passed without `aflag` being set.

So all in all, it would look like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int flags, opt;
  int nsecs, tfnd;
  int aflag;

  nsecs = 0;
  tfnd = 0;
  flags = 0;
  aflag = 0;
  while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "ant:")) != -1)
    {
      switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
          aflag = 1;
          break;
        case 'n':
          flags = 1;
          break;
        case 't':
          nsecs = atoi (optarg);
          tfnd = 1;
          break;
        default:               /* '?' */
          fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s [-t nsecs] [-n] name\n", argv[0]);
          exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

  printf ("flags=%d; tfnd=%d; optind=%d\n", flags, tfnd, optind);

  if (optind >= argc)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Expected argument after options\n");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  if (!aflag && (flags || tfnd))
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Must specify a flag to use n or t flag\n");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  printf ("name argument = %s\n", argv[optind]);

  /* Other code omitted */

  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```